# Understanding Props Passed to router-view for Vue Child Component, Prop Data Not Rendering

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, vue-props

I know this has been asked in several other posts on StackOverflow, though I'm still running into a wall with trying to solve my issue. I'm very much new to Vue and trying to learn this stack but having some struggles with this aspect

PROBLEM: In following along with a tutorial I have a page called "Menu Editor" that uses Vue Router to automatically redirect the user to a child component called "Category Manager" within the Menu Editor page. However, when on the "Menu Editor" page the prop data will not show regardless of what I've attempted thus far (reading and trying solutions proposed in similar posts such as this)
from my menu editor vue file, i know the issue lies with
`<router-view v-bind:inital-categories="categories"></router-view>`

**from my app.js file I have my two components registered as such**

```
   Vue.component('category-manager', require('./components/category-manager.vue').default);
   Vue.component('menu-editor', require('./components/menu-editor.vue').default);
```

**my menu-editor.vue file**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Menu Editor</h1>
        <router-link :to="{name: 'categories'}">Categories</router-link>
        <router-link :to="{name: 'add-item'}">Add Item</router-link>

        <router-view v-bind:inital-categories="categories"></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    import CategoryManager from './category-manager.vue';
    import MenuItem from './menu-item.vue';

    export default {
        props:['categories'],
        router: new VueRouter({
            mode: 'history',
            routes: [
                {
                    path: '/categories',
                    name: 'categories',
                    component: CategoryManager
                },
                {
                    path: '/menu-editor',
                    redirect: {name: 'categories'}
                },
                {
                    path: '/add-item',
                    name: 'add-item',
                    component: MenuItem
                }
            ]
        })
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    a{
        border: solid 1px black;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .router-link-active{
        font-weight: bold;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
</style>
```

**my category-manager.vue file**

```
<template>
    <form  @submit.prevent="saveCategories">
        <a @click="addCategory(index)" class="add">+ add category</a>

        <div v-for="(category,index) of categories" :key="category.id">
            <input type="text" v-model="category.name" :ref="category.name">
            <input type="number" v-model="category.display_order">
            <a @click="removeCategory(index)" class="remove">delete</a>
            <div>
                <img v-if="category.image" :src="`/images/${category.image}`" width="100">
                <label v-else>Image: </label>
                <input type="text" v-model.lazy="category.image">
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        <div>{{ feedback }}</div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['initialCategories'],
        data(){
            return{
                categories: _.cloneDeep(this.initialCategories),
                feedback: '',
            };
        },
        methods: {
            removeCategory(index){
                if(confirm('are you sure?')){
                    let id = this.categories[index].id;
                    if(id > 0){
                        console.log('calling delete /api/categories/' + id);
                        axios.delete('/api/categories/' + id);
                    }
                    this.categories.splice(index,1);
                }
            },
            addCategory(index){
                this.categories.push({
                    id: 0,
                    name: '',
                    display_order: this.categories.length + 1
                });
                this.$nextTick(() =>{
                    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
                    this.$refs[''][0].focus();
                });
            },
            saveCategories(){
                axios.post('/api/categories/upsert', {
                    categories: this.categories
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    if(res.data.success){
                        this.feedback = 'Changes saved.';
                        categories = res.data.categories;
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    img {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    hr {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

**my menu-editor.blade.php file**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', '- Menu Editor')

@section('content')
    <menu-editor :categories="{{ $categories }}"></menu-editor>
@endsection
```

**my AdminController.php file**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Categories;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    //
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function menu(){
        //
        $categories = Categories::orderBy('display_order')->get();
        return view('admin.menu-editor', [
            'categories' => $categories
        ]);
    }
}
```

When on the "Menu Editor" the view returns as such
[image: menu editor]

with the data returned to the DOM as "[object Object],[object Object]" instead of the objects being rendered correctly.
`inital-categories="[object Object],[object Object]"`

However, when I go directly to the "/categories" page *without* first going to the "Menu Editor", the data shows fine.

This is what the "categories" page looks like when visited directly (without having the two menu buttons at the top of the page as the Menu Editor does)
[image: category manager]

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong so that I can correctly show the prop data on the Menu-Editor page? Thanks in advance! I'm sure that I'm overlooking something silly but would really appreciate any help in finding and fixing my error.

Comment: Just use Vuex, you will be thank full.

Comment: Are you sure the redirect is taking place?

Comment: Hello @BülentAkgül , I am almost positive that in the next portion of the course they end up refactoring the functionality using Vuex so if I cannot figure this out, I may just end up skipping forward to that piece though I'd like to try and solve this first before throwing in the towel.

Comment: @MaartenVeerman Yeah the redirect happens on '/menu-editor' for that portion, as far as I can tell. When I hit that page the Category Manager component loads though the data never makes it, but after the initial load of 'menu-editor' if I refresh the page, it will take me entirely to the second photos "Categories" page without the two buttons on "Menu Editor" (categories and add items). Though does that behavior sound like the redirect is properly applying to you? I'm definitely not very experienced with this, so I very well may be misunderstanding